# how can I configure maxscale with one master mariadb server, 3 slave mariadb server?

Tags: mariadb, maxscale

I need database proxy. Because I need to setup write/read queries and especially row sharding. I found and installed maxscale. How can I configure maxscale with one master mariadb server, 3 slave mariadb server? The original documentation is not good about my problem.

Answer (score 1):

The [MaxScale read-write splitting tutorial](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb-enterprise/mariadb-maxscale-22-readwrite-splitting-with-mariadb-maxscale/) covers setting up a replicated cluster with one master and two slaves. You can add the third slave by simply adding another server definition and adding it to the list of names in the `servers` parameter of the service.

Here's an example configuration with four servers (one master and three slaves) configured with read-write splitting.

```
[maxscale]
threads=auto

[server1]
type=server
address=192.168.0.101
port=3306
protocol=MariaDBBackend

[server2]
type=server
address=192.168.0.102
port=3306
protocol=MariaDBBackend

[server3]
type=server
address=192.168.0.103
port=3306
protocol=MariaDBBackend

[server4]
type=server
address=192.168.0.104
port=3306
protocol=MariaDBBackend

[MariaDB-Monitor]
type=monitor
module=mariadbmon
servers=server1,server2,server3,server4
user=maxuser
password=maxpwd
monitor_interval=5000

[RW-Split-Router]
type=service
router=readwritesplit
servers=server1,server2,server3,server4
user=maxuser
password=maxpwd

[RW-Split-Listener]
type=listener
service=RW-Split-Router
protocol=MariaDBClient
port=3306
```

The `mariadbmon` automatically detects which server is the master so you don't need to tell MaxScale which server is the master.

Comment: This configuration is the same like mine. I tested as a splitter service, it works fine. How can I shard by row?

Comment: For row level sharding, the Spider engine is a good solution: https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/spider-storage-engine-overview/